# how to auto expand the height of TextView when text line/material is large

Tags: android, textview

I am working on an app and i am facing a problem about height of text view w.r.t text data.

i explain my problem with an example,

Suppose i have data like that:

String data = "In India in 1987, Khan led Pakistan in its first-ever Test series win and this was followed by Pakistan's first series victory."

and this data can easily be fit textview. But if the size of data become large like

String data = "In India in 1987, Khan led Pakistan in its first-ever Test series win and this was followed by Pakistan's first series victory,Khan led Pakistan in its first-ever Test series win and this was followed by Pakistan's first series victory."

Then is that case, the remaining part of data is not shown within the height of textView.

My question is how to dynamically increase the height of textivew for large data keeping in mind the following requirements

1. Text size is fixed e.g "14dp"
2. only size/height of textView should be increased
3. I have not to use the scroll view for large data, i only want to use scroll view when the size of data (eventually TextView) become large enough the size of screen, then i want to use scrollView only, to vertically scroll.

Can any one give the good solution, for this described problem. please share some snipt of code for my better understanding. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show snippet of your xml code please.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the height attribute of your textview to wrap_content in your xml

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works for me

Comment: Great! Then hit this check sign to accept the answer so the others know it works!

Answer (score 0):

Just make your texview scrollable:

- XML Side:

  android:scrollbars = "vertical"
- Java Side:

  Textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());